# Include websites in literature review section of paper?

Tags: citations

I am writing an APA style literature review synthesis paper for a class. This week we are working on the Literature Review section of the paper, including statistics found from the articles we are reviewing. I will be citing and reference websites such as HHS.gov (for information on HIPAA) and Merriam Webster's Online Dictionary for a definition. My question is, do I write a paragraph about these websites in the Literature Review section of my paper? 
I hope this isn't too confusing. I've emailed my instructor 3 times, but she is not understanding what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're just getting one or two facts from each of those sources. Just cite them briefly in the Introduction (or whatever part of the paper you introduce that information and definition). The reader will see that they are official government sources, a dictionary, etc., that you are citing for one fact, and so you do not need to spend time introducing the source in the text. The references to the websites should then go in the "References" section at the end so people can look them up.

If you were doing a literature review about how a word changed over time, then perhaps it would be appropriate to cite the dictionary entry there. That is, if there is a substantial chunk of content from that source, then it is an appropriate one to talk about in detail in the Literature Review section. Mainly, a Literature Review in a research article is there to set up: "Here's what other scholars have said about this topic," and you include some summary, critique, and synthesis. (Your assignment may have you spreading out the critique or synthesis into other sections.)

Comment: Yes! Only a few facts from each site and they will be cited in the body of the paper and referenced on the reference page. Thank you so much!